# AD B2C Custom Policy increment number of failed login attempts

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have a requirement to lock out a user permanently after X amount of failed login attempts. I'm still using the smart lock feature from AD B2C for any attempts below that X number. I'm using custom policies and I can't figure out how to track the failed attempts number.

I have created a custom claim (extension_attempt) to represent the login attempts and I have been able to increase that number every time the user logs in. I am also able to lock out the user. I'm doing this via orchestration steps in the login user journey, each pointing to their corresponding technical profile.

However, I don't know how to **call the increment when login fails**. Right now it only does this on success (which makes sense based on my implementation).

My orchestration steps look like this:

```
<!-- Increment attempt-->
<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="OSIncrementAttempt" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="TPIncrementAttempt"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<!-- Save attempt-->
<OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
       <ClaimsExchange Id="OSSaveAttempt" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="TPISaveAttempt"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

My Technical Profiles:

```
<TechnicalProfile id="TPIncrementAttempt">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_attempt" DefaultValue="1"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="IncrementAttempt"/>
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Comon"/>
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile id="TPISaveAttempt">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_attempt"/>
    </PersistedClaims>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Comon"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I'm new to custom policies in AD B2C, so my question might be obvious.

**EDIT**

In the extension policy, my "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" Technical Profile looks like this now (I haven't added my other technical profiles yet):

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true"  />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" /> 
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

But it fails when I add "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress". I have tried adding an "email" outputclaim and transform it using "CopyClaim" so it has the same value as "signInName", but it didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

As this would need to happen as the user clicks the sign-in button it cannot be achieved via orchestration steps but instead as validation technical profiles.

You would need to add custom logic to the SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email technical profile validation technical profiles.

Below is a start to how this could be achieved. Note, this is untested and `Disable-Account-Technical-Profile` would need to be implemented.

```
<!-- This technical profile uses a validation technical profile to authenticate the user. -->
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
    <Item Key="AssertNumberError">You've reached the maximum logon attempts</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="TPIncrementAttempt" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="TPISaveAttempt" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Disable-Account-Technical-Profile">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_attempt</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
    </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AssertSignInAttemptsValid" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
    <!-- reset login attempts if successful -->
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="TPResetLoginAttempts" /> 
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="AssertSignInAttemptsValid">
  <DisplayName>Unit test</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="result" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CT-AssertSignInAttemptsValid" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>

<ClaimsTransformation Id="CT-AssertSignInAttemptsValid" TransformationMethod="AssertNumber">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_attempt" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="Operator" DataType="string" Value="GreaterThanOrEqual" />
    <InputParameter Id="CompareToValue" DataType="int" Value="10" />
    <InputParameter Id="throwError" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="result" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: I get the error "Unable to validate the information provided" when I add the VTP "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress". I'm assuming it's because it's expecting "email" to be returned as an output claim from "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email", but even if I add it, it doesn't work. I'm sorry if this is obvious @bolt-io

Comment: What does your sign-in technical profile look like? Can you include it here?

Comment: I've used the LocalAccounts starterpack so the one in my base file is the same as this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml. I've updated the description of my post to show the changes I made in the extension file @bolt-io

Comment: `AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress` requires an `email` claim but `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email` collects it as `signInName`. You would need to add another validation technical profile to copy `signInName` to `email` or an input claims transformation on `AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress`